# Exploratory factor analysis for binary data with high number of variables

Tags: r

I have a binary dataset example like this one:

```
DF <- data.frame(text = c(0, 0, 0, 1), text.1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0), "text sth"=c(1, 0, 0, 0))
```

I try to make factor analysis using this:

```
efa <- factanal(DF, factors=2, rotation="varimax")
```

but I receive this error:

```
Error in solve.default(cv) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[11,11] = 0
```

The example I checked it wasn't for binary data. Is there any problem because my data are binary and I receive this error?

My dataset has 53 variables and 6357 objects.

If I run the factanal() for only 6variables and 6357 objects it works fine. What can I do to run factanal for 53 varibles?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an authority in this, but I am fairly confident what is below is correct.

1. What `factanal` expects is a set of numerical values - i.e. continuous data. What you have *aren't continuous* data, so your analysis, even when it works, may mislead you.
2. What `factanal` does is a decomposition of the covariance matrix, see "..factor analysis is in essence a model for the correlation matrix of" from the Help. The error you get says there is problem in getting an inverse of a matrix.

   This matrix probably is the covariance matrix, and if so, the error can occur if some columns are closely similar. See also about [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity).

Since the input to `factanal` can be a covariance matrix. So, your best bet to do this is to remove dependent variables and covariance matrix from your data. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67019/variance-and-covariance-of-binary-data) for the latter.

If you were able to do this, best post that as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should give the matrix instead of your data (DF) to factanal. From the library(polycor) use the next lines:

```
V1 <- hetcor(df.2)$cor

factanal(covmat = V1, factors = 2, rotation = "varimax")
```

You can get more info in the next link: https://it.unt.edu/sites/default/files/binaryfa_l_jds_sep2014_0.pdf